# How do i batch multiple select query calls into a single mysql query or procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have this function which checks friendship status between 2 users using their userIds and it is working fine.

```
function checkFriendShipBetweenUsers(user1Id, user2Id) {

    var checkFriendShipBetweenUsersQuery = "SELECT status  FROM friends WHERE (user1Id=? AND user2Id =?) OR (user1Id=? AND user2Id =?)"
    var queryParameterList = [user1Id, user2Id, user2Id, user1Id]

}
```

I have a case in which i need to check friendship status between a user and other 3 users.
I can call above function 3 times, one for each other user to get desired result but i would like to make it with a single db call using a single query or using a mysql procedure.

```
function checkFriendShipBetweenUsers(user1Id, userIdList) {

    var checkFriendShipBetweenUsersQuery = ""
    var queryParameterList = []

}
```

So this query/procedure call should return 3 integers indicating user1's friendship status with users in userIdList.

Here is an example db fiddle:
db-fiddle.com/f/p5RP61V3AcawRgJcogeXey/1

given user1Id : 'a8t57h6p8n2efden' and

userIdList : ['typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2', 'cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl', '0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0']

How do i write such query or procedure?

Comment: What is MySQL version? show output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: it is version 8.0.28

Comment: Can you provide this "other N users" list as single string literal in CSV or JSON array format? For example like solid `'[123,456,789]'` value?

Comment: yes i can provide it

Comment: Add into the question: sample data for reproducing the solution - CREATE TABLE for `friends` table, INSERT INTO with some data (5-7 rows), current user ID, array with the user IDs to be tested (3 values as one JSON, some are present and some are not), desired MySQL output for this data (for example as a rowset userId-status). Source data may be provided as a link on the online fiddle.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p5RP61V3AcawRgJcogeXey/1         given user1Id : 'a8t57h6p8n2efden'       and userIdList : ['typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2', 'cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl', '0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO

```
-- source data
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  user1Id VARCHAR(100),
  user2Id VARCHAR(100),
  status INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id,user1Id,user2Id,status) VALUES 
  (1,'a8t57h6p8n2efden','typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2',0),
  (2,'cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl','a8t57h6p8n2efden',1),
  (3,'0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0','a8t57h6p8n2efden',2),
  (4,'a8t57h6p8n2efden','ap21wzbew0bprt5t',0);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | user1Id | user2Id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a8t57h6p8n2efden | typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2 | 0 |
| 2 | cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl | a8t57h6p8n2efden | 1 |
| 3 | 0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0 | a8t57h6p8n2efden | 2 |
| 4 | a8t57h6p8n2efden | ap21wzbew0bprt5t | 0 |

```
-- searching parameters
SET @user1Id := 'a8t57h6p8n2efden';
SET @userIdList := '[
  "typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2",
  "cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl", 
  "0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0", 
  "absent value"
  ]';
```

```
SELECT jsontable.userid, test.status
FROM JSON_TABLE( @userIdList,
                 '$[*]' COLUMNS ( rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
                                  userid VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
                                  )) jsontable
LEFT JOIN test
  ON (@user1Id, jsontable.userid) IN ( (test.user1Id, test.user2Id), 
                                       (test.user2Id, test.user1Id)
                                       )
```

| userid | status |
| --- | --- |
| typ3vg6xb1vt7nw2 | 0 |
| cy6mqqyykpldc2j1g5vm5cqsi6x1dgrl | 1 |
| 0bw87kprb97pes1crom8ceodi07r2kd0 | 2 |
| absent value | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sjbW8czL)

If you do not need `status` value for the IDs which are not found then use INNER JOIN.

If you want to receive the output as one solid value then add according GROUP BY and aggregation. Use `jsontable.rowid` for to provide needed values ordering.

PS. If you won't use an aggregation then you may do not obtain `rowid` value - simply remove `rowid FOR ORDINALITY,` in this case.