# MySQL add in bulk by passing data in argument for procedure

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

after searching for a while I could not find a way to add rows in bulk by passing in argument for example a list of values. I know that it is possible to create a for loop, but it would insert each value separately n times, which I assume is bad performancewise. Here is a sample of what I have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE \`spLogAdd\`(
  IN \`userId\` VARCHAR(255),
  IN \`isActive\` BIT,
  IN \`valueDatetime\` DATETIME,
  IN \`valueId\` INT
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log_table (user_id, is_active, value_datetime, valueId) 
  VALUES (\`userId\`, \`isActive\`, \`valueDatetime\`, \`valueId\`);            
END;
```

What I would like to have is a list of userIds('1,2,3,4,5,6') to insert multiple rows with 1 then 2 and so on at once. Other arguments do not need to change. If there is any neat way, please help me to do that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE \`spLogBulkAdd\`(
  IN \`userId\` VARCHAR(255),
  IN \`isActive\` BIT,
  IN \`valueDatetime\` DATETIME,
  IN \`valueId\` INT
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log_table (user_id, is_active, value_datetime, valueId) 
  VALUES (\`userId\`, \`isActive\`, \`valueDatetime\`, \`valueId\`);            
END;
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do you say 'insert multiple rows with 1 then 2 and so on ' but you don't have a way of defining multiple and you don't say what the other column values should be for each iteration.

Comment: Parse your CSV to rowset then insert. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531900/10138734